# how to use a whole hive database in spark and read sql queries from external files?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, tpc

I am using hortonworks sandbox in Azure with spark 1.6.
I have a Hive database populated with TPC-DS sample data. I want to read some SQL queries from external files and run them on the hive dataset in spark.
I follow this topic [Using hive database in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770503/using-hive-database-in-spark) which is just using a table in my dataset and also it writes SQL query in spark again, but I need to define whole, dataset as my source to query on that, I think i should use dataframes but i am not sure and do not know how!
also I want to import the SQL query from external .sql file and do not write down the query again!
would you please guide me how can I do this?
thank you very much,
bests!

Comment: You can read your query from property files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark Can read data directly from Hive table. You can create, drop Hive table using Spark and even you can do all Hive hql related operations through the Spark. For this you need to use Spark `HiveContext`

**From the Spark documentation:**

Spark HiveContext, provides a superset of the functionality provided by the basic SQLContext. Additional features include the ability to write queries using the more complete HiveQL parser, access to Hive UDFs, and the ability to read data from Hive tables. To use a HiveContext, you do not need to have an existing Hive setup.

For more information you can visit [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html)

To Avoid writing sql in code, you can use property file where you can put all your Hive query and then you can use the key in you code.

Please see below the implementation of Spark HiveContext and use of property file in Spark Scala.

```
package com.spark.hive.poc

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

//Import Row.
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
//Import Spark SQL data types
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, StringType };

object ReadPropertyFiles extends Serializable {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("read local file");

  conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "100M");
  conf.setMaster("local");

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var hadoopConf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
    var fileSystem = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf);
    var Path = new Path(args(0));
    val inputStream = fileSystem.open(Path);
    var Properties = new java.util.Properties;
    Properties.load(inputStream);

    //Create an RDD
    val people = sc.textFile("/user/User1/spark_hive_poc/input/");
    //The schema is encoded in a string
    val schemaString = "name address";

    //Generate the schema based on the string of schema
    val schema =
      StructType(
        schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)));

    //Convert records of the RDD (people) to Rows.
    val rowRDD = people.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0), p(1).trim));
    //Apply the schema to the RDD.
    val peopleDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
    peopleDataFrame.printSchema();

    peopleDataFrame.registerTempTable("tbl_temp")

    val data = sqlContext.sql(Properties.getProperty("temp_table"));

    //Drop Hive table
    sqlContext.sql(Properties.getProperty("drop_hive_table"));
    //Create Hive table
    sqlContext.sql(Properties.getProperty("create_hive_tavle"));
    //Insert data into Hive table
    sqlContext.sql(Properties.getProperty("insert_into_hive_table"));
    //Select Data into Hive table
    sqlContext.sql(Properties.getProperty("select_from_hive")).show();

    sc.stop

  }
}
```

**Entry in Properties File :**

```
temp_table=select * from tbl_temp
drop_hive_table=DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.test_hive_tbl
create_hive_tavle=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.test_hive_tbl(name string, city string) STORED AS ORC
insert_into_hive_table=insert overwrite table default.test_hive_tbl select * from tbl_temp
select_from_hive=select * from default.test_hive_tbl
```

**Spark submit Command to run this job:**

```
[User1@hadoopdev ~]$ spark-submit --num-executors 1 \
--executor-memory 100M --total-executor-cores 2 --master local \
--class com.spark.hive.poc.ReadPropertyFiles Hive-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
/user/User1/spark_hive_poc/properties/sql.properties
```

**Note:** Property File location should be HDFS location.

Comment: Thank you Dear @sandeep-singh. in fact I have 2 different databases (both with same tables) in hive. I am a bit confused how to select my preferred database?

ps, in Hive I was using like this:   use DB1 but I do not know how to do this here.

thanks

Comment: In query I  have used `default.test_hive_tbl` where `default` is my database and `test_hive_tb` is my table name. in your query you will also associate your database_name with table_name.

Comment: You don't need to write `use <database>` just associate with the `table_name`  as I did.

Comment: Dear Sandeep, thank you for your comments.
as I understand "ReadPropertyFiles" is my Scala application and: I have an application (first part of your code) which is using queries in Properties File (second part of your code) and finally it will be executed by the last part of your code.
I have some questions about that:
1-should i write the main code and save it somewhere? what is the file format and where i should save?
2- what is "val schemaString = "name address";" and what is it used for.

thank you very much

Comment: `SchemaString` is additional, I used to provide a schema to `DataFrame`. I will update the answer and remove additional logic. You can save the output and avro, parquet or orc as per your requirement or you can also insert your analysed output into another hive table.

Comment: dear Sandeep , would you please help me to know how to run this code? I dont know where should I save my scala code and how to save it. someone remove my previous request for guidance.
i am so confused about where and how to save this code with which format and also how should i provide that JAR files which you mentioned in running phase.
thank you very much man

Comment: You can create a maven Scala project in eclipse and then you can start coading. These links will help you http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047186/creating-the-most-basic-scala-project-with-maven